# SNMP configuration on dell S5000 switch

Tags: snmp, switching, monitoring, dell

I am setting up some monitoring tools for my works network and there are two core switches that I need to be monitoring all the time. I have snmp configured on the switch but when I try to add it as an item on my monitoring tools it will not add it. I can ping the IP address I want to monitor from the server.  The current configuration on the switch (Dell S5000) looks like this:

```
*******#show running-config | find snmp
snmp-server community "**********" rw,
snmp-server enable traps bgp,
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication coldstart linkdown linkup syslog-re                                                                                                             achable syslog-unreachable,
snmp-server enable traps vrrp,
snmp-server enable traps lacp,
snmp-server enable traps entity,
snmp-server enable traps stack,
snmp-server enable traps stp,
snmp-server enable traps ecfm,
snmp-server enable traps vlt,
snmp-server enable traps fips,
snmp-server enable traps ets,
snmp-server enable traps xstp,
snmp-server enable traps isis,
snmp-server enable traps config,
snmp-server enable traps pfc,
snmp-server enable traps envmon cam-utilization fan supply temperature,
snmp-server enable traps ecmp.
```

I'm thinking the problem is I'm not assigning the traps to an interface? The SNMP community string is defo a match. If any of you have any other ideas, i'd greatly appreciate your input.

Comment: Can you try using something like Paessler SNMP Tester to see if you can get at least the uptime of the switch? This will at least tell you whether its your monitoring tool or the switch configuration that is the issue.

Comment: Got the following response: MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = No response (check: firewalls, routing, snmp settings of device, IPs, SNMP version, community, passwords etc) (SNMP error # -2003) ( 0 seconds )
05/07/2016 09:54:43 (4058 ms) : SNMP Datatype: ASN_PRIMITIVE
05/07/2016 09:54:43 (4068 ms) : HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemUptime.0 = No response (check: firewalls, routing, snmp settings of device, IPs, SNMP version, community, passwords etc) (SNMP error # -2003) ( 0 seconds )
05/07/2016 09:54:44 (4076 ms) : Done

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sleepy Man, this is a really useful tool. Just going through the checklist of things to make sure I haven't messed up somewhere. I dont think its the firewall as the switch sits before it, the routing is fine as I can ping and traceroute from the server to it, The community string is correct.also. Will have another play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved after finding a typo in the community string.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Sometimes it helps using another tool to verify where the issue is :)

Comment: You should accept your answer so that this question doesn't keep popping up and looking for an answer.